# Is there a get_method() function in PHP?

Tags: php

In one class I call $this->view() which will be handled by its extended class. But how can I get the name of the method in the parent view();

To make it somewhat clearer:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends Controller
    public function signup() {
        $this->view();
    }
}
class Controller {
    public function view() {
        // How can I get 'signup' so that I can include 'views/Users/signup.php'
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could, in theory, determine the name of the calling method with [`debug_bugtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), the far simpler (and *therefore better*) solution is:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
    public function signup() {
        $this->view(__FUNCTION__);
    }
    public function signup_from_facebook() {
        // Do some facebook-y stuff here
        $this->view('signup');
    }
}
class Controller {
    public function view($page) {
        include 'views/Users/' . $page . '.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: One more argument against `debug_backtrace()` is that it is slowwww.

Comment: I was hoping to reserve the variable for when the view filename is different than the method..

Comment: @Pekka Yes, and its extremely error-prone, and horrible style.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs Added an example (a related controller that uses the same view) for that.

Comment: I just tested, `__METHOD__` will return `ClassName::MethodName`. `__FUNCTION__` seems the way to go

Comment: @phihag I've just started using it in a bug tracker and it works marvellously. Not to mention fast - with ticks it get called about a hundred times in the pageload, but the page generation time is barely a millisecond slower than without. Maybe you're just using it wrong :p

Answer (score 2):

The only fully automatic way is using `debug_backtrace()` but that is really slow and hence not a good idea.

The best semi-automatic way that comes to mind is using the `__FUNCTION__` [magic constant:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
 <?php
class UsersController extends Controller
    public function signup() {
        $this->view(__FUNCTION__);
    }
}
class Controller {
    public function view($methodname) {
        echo $methodname; // will output "signup"
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I was hoping to reserve the variable for when the view filename is different than the method..